# Elasticsearch unable to recognize regular expression

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am new to ES. My data sets have the following fields

```
type | path
```

I want to search for the following values of the field

```
type field having value 'at'
path field having values in the following form like '/abc123' , '/abc456789','/abc7891 etc ..
```

So I have written the following query

```
{
"filter": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": "2017-07-04",
          "lte": "2017-07-05"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
 }
},
"query": {
 "filtered": {
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "at"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "path": {
              "value": "/abc[0-9]+"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
     }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

But the above query is not filtering on the basis of regular expression; could anyone please point out what is wrong in this code, and how can this be modified so that ES gives back the results incorporating regular expression also?

Comment: ES regex is anchored by default. Does your `/abc[0-9]+` match the whole input string? If not, try `.*/abc[0-9].*`

Comment: It matches the whole input string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew '/abc' is fixed the remianing numericals could be any string of number

Comment: Yeah, there must be some issue with the query itself.